# Using php code in .twig file slim framework

Tags: php, twig, slim

I am using Slim Framework for the first time and also using twig for templatizing. I have a **land.twig** file the contents of that file are

```
 <form action="index.html" method="get">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name">
          </div>
</form>
```

I also have a **string file** to support multi-language and the way I call the string for translation is **lang("some_string");**. The **land.twig** file is rendered by a controller. My question is how can I add lang("some_string") within placeholder attribute for html elements  in that twig file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use Twig_SimpleFilter.

```
require_once '/path/to/lib/Twig/Autoloader.php';
Twig_Autoloader::register();

$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('/path/to/templates');
// an anonymous function
$filter = new Twig_SimpleFilter('lang', function ($string) {
    //do stuff
    return $string;
});

$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$twig->addFilter($filter);
```

Then in your template you can use

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ 'Full Name'|lang }}">
```

Since you are using slim and its twig integration you have to add the filter within the twig component.

```
// Register component on container
$container['view'] = function ($container) {
   $view = new \Slim\Views\Twig('path/to/templates', [
       'cache' => 'path/to/cache'
    ]);
    $view->addExtension(new \Slim\Views\TwigExtension(
        $container['router'],
        $container['request']->getUri()
    ));

    $filter = new Twig_SimpleFilter('lang', function ($string) {
        //do stuff
        return $string;
    });

    $view->getEnvironment()->addFilter($filter);

    return $view;
};
```

Other than that twig has a [i18n extension](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/i18n.html).

Comment: Where shall i put this anonymous function? in the bootstrap file?

Comment: Does not matter where. Wherever you define your twig enviroment you have to define and the the filter afterwards.

Comment: Edited the post. Basically tells twig where to find the templates. http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html) When you already got rendered pages in twig you should already have done this.

Comment: getting warning as
Unknown "lang" filter in "land.twig" at line 73.
Line 73 is the placeholder

Comment: Then you did not correctly add the Twig_SimpleFilter 'lang' to your twig enviroment using addFilter as shown above. Since you are using the integration of Slim I modified my example again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121244/discussion-between-shiva-acharjee-and-horst-jahns).